# Nan in summary histogram softmax_linear/biases/gradients during running CIFAR-10 tutorial modified for custom training data

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to modify the CIFAR-10 tutorial in TensorFlow models repository to feed custom data and customize training parameters and layers, I have 3 convolution layers and 2 fully connected layer. My training data has 2310 24x24 grayscale images, it just worked fine before I changed the optimizer to AdamOptimizer, but now I'm getting some error, that doesn't even being solved after I changed the optimizer back to GradientDescentOptimizer:

```
cro@deep03:~/image/cifar10_mod$ python3 cifar10_train.py
Filling queue with 924 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
2017-07-19 17:26:55.586361: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-19 17:26:55.586379: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-19 17:26:55.586386: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-19 17:26:55.586391: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-19 17:26:55.586412: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-19 17:26:55.697215: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-07-19 17:26:55.697464: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7845
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 5.93GiB
Free memory: 5.80GiB
2017-07-19 17:26:55.697475: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
2017-07-19 17:26:55.697479: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
2017-07-19 17:26:55.697484: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-07-19 17:26:56.594088: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: Nan in summary histogram for: softmax_linear/biases/gradients
     [[Node: softmax_linear/biases/gradients = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](softmax_linear/biases/gradients/tag, gradients/softmax_linear/softmax_linear_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_285)]]

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram for: softmax_linear/biases/gradients
     [[Node: softmax_linear/biases/gradients = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](softmax_linear/biases/gradients/tag, gradients/softmax_linear/softmax_linear_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_285)]]
cro@deep03:~/image/cifar10_mod$
```

Here's my code:

file cifar10.py:

```
# pylint: disable=missing-docstring
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import re
import sys
import tarfile

from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow as tf

import cifar10_input

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

# Basic model parameters.
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 100,
                            """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', '/tmp/cifar10_data',
                           """Path to the CIFAR-10 data directory.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_boolean('use_fp16', False,
                            """Train the model using fp16.""")

# Global constants describing the CIFAR-10 data set.
IMAGE_SIZE = cifar10_input.IMAGE_SIZE
NUM_CLASSES = cifar10_input.NUM_CLASSES
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = cifar10_input.NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = cifar10_input.NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL


# Constants describing the training process.
MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY = 0.9999     # The decay to use for the moving average.
NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY = 50.0      # Epochs after which learning rate decays.
LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR = 0.1  # Learning rate decay factor.
INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE = 0.1       # Initial learning rate.

# If a model is trained with multiple GPUs, prefix all Op names with tower_name
# to differentiate the operations. Note that this prefix is removed from the
# names of the summaries when visualizing a model.
TOWER_NAME = 'tower'

DATA_URL = 'http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-binary.tar.gz'


def _activation_summary(x):
  """Helper to create summaries for activations.
  Creates a summary that provides a histogram of activations.
  Creates a summary that measures the sparsity of activations.
  Args:
    x: Tensor
  Returns:
    nothing
  """
  # Remove 'tower_[0-9]/' from the name in case this is a multi-GPU training
  # session. This helps the clarity of presentation on tensorboard.
  tensor_name = re.sub('%s_[0-9]*/' % TOWER_NAME, '', x.op.name)
  tf.summary.histogram(tensor_name + '/activations', x)
  tf.summary.scalar(tensor_name + '/sparsity',
                                       tf.nn.zero_fraction(x))


def _variable_on_cpu(name, shape, initializer):
  """Helper to create a Variable stored on CPU memory.
  Args:
    name: name of the variable
    shape: list of ints
    initializer: initializer for Variable
  Returns:
    Variable Tensor
  """
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    dtype = tf.float16 if FLAGS.use_fp16 else tf.float32
    var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=initializer, dtype=dtype)
  return var


def _variable_with_weight_decay(name, shape, stddev, wd):
  """Helper to create an initialized Variable with weight decay.
  Note that the Variable is initialized with a truncated normal distribution.
  A weight decay is added only if one is specified.
  Args:
    name: name of the variable
    shape: list of ints
    stddev: standard deviation of a truncated Gaussian
    wd: add L2Loss weight decay multiplied by this float. If None, weight
        decay is not added for this Variable.
  Returns:
    Variable Tensor
  """
  dtype = tf.float16 if FLAGS.use_fp16 else tf.float32
  var = _variable_on_cpu(
      name,
      shape,
      tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev, dtype=dtype))
  if wd is not None:
    weight_decay = tf.multiply(tf.nn.l2_loss(var), wd, name='weight_loss')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', weight_decay)
  return var


def distorted_inputs():
  """Construct distorted input for CIFAR training using the Reader ops.
  Returns:
    images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3] size.
    labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
  Raises:
    ValueError: If no data_dir
  """
  if not FLAGS.data_dir:
    raise ValueError('Please supply a data_dir')
  data_dir = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'cifar-10-batches-bin')
  images, labels = cifar10_input.distorted_inputs(data_dir=data_dir,
                                                  batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  if FLAGS.use_fp16:
    images = tf.cast(images, tf.float16)
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float16)
  return images, labels


def inputs(eval_data):
  """Construct input for CIFAR evaluation using the Reader ops.
  Args:
    eval_data: bool, indicating if one should use the train or eval data set.
  Returns:
    images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3] size.
    labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
  Raises:
    ValueError: If no data_dir
  """
  if not FLAGS.data_dir:
    raise ValueError('Please supply a data_dir')
  data_dir = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'cifar-10-batches-bin')
  images, labels = cifar10_input.inputs(eval_data=eval_data,
                                        data_dir=data_dir,
                                        batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  if FLAGS.use_fp16:
    images = tf.cast(images, tf.float16)
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float16)
  return images, labels


def inference(images):
  """Build the CIFAR-10 model.
  Args:
    images: Images returned from distorted_inputs() or inputs().
  Returns:
    Logits.
  """
  # We instantiate all variables using tf.get_variable() instead of
  # tf.Variable() in order to share variables across multiple GPU training runs.
  # If we only ran this model on a single GPU, we could simplify this function
  # by replacing all instances of tf.get_variable() with tf.Variable().
  #
  # conv1
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                         shape=[5, 5, 1, 128],
                                         stddev=5e-2,
                                         wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [128], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)

  # pool1
  pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         padding='SAME', name='pool1')
  norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                    name='norm1')

  # conv2
  with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                         shape=[5, 5, 128, 128],
                                         stddev=5e-2,
                                         wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [128], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv2)

  # pool2
  pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')
  norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(pool2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                    name='norm1')

  # conv2
  with tf.variable_scope('conv3') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                         shape=[5, 5, 128, 128],
                                         stddev=5e-2,
                                         wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [128], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv3)

  # pool2
  pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')
  norm3 = tf.nn.lrn(pool3, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                    name='norm3')


  # local3
  with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
    # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
    reshape = tf.reshape(norm3, [FLAGS.batch_size, -1])
    dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 512],
                                          stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [512], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(local3)


  # linear layer(WX + b),
  # We don't apply softmax here because
  # tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits accepts the unscaled logits
  # and performs the softmax internally for efficiency.
  with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [512, NUM_CLASSES],
                                          stddev=1/192.0, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [NUM_CLASSES],
                              tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    print(biases)
    softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local3, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(softmax_linear)

  return softmax_linear


def loss(logits, labels):
  """Add L2Loss to all the trainable variables.
  Add summary for "Loss" and "Loss/avg".
  Args:
    logits: Logits from inference().
    labels: Labels from distorted_inputs or inputs(). 1-D tensor
            of shape [batch_size]
  Returns:
    Loss tensor of type float.
  """
  # Calculate the average cross entropy loss across the batch.
  labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
  cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      labels=labels, logits=logits, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
  cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy')
  tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)

  # The total loss is defined as the cross entropy loss plus all of the weight
  # decay terms (L2 loss).
  return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')


def _add_loss_summaries(total_loss):
  """Add summaries for losses in CIFAR-10 model.
  Generates moving average for all losses and associated summaries for
  visualizing the performance of the network.
  Args:
    total_loss: Total loss from loss().
  Returns:
    loss_averages_op: op for generating moving averages of losses.
  """
  # Compute the moving average of all individual losses and the total loss.
  loss_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9, name='avg')
  losses = tf.get_collection('losses')
  loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply(losses + [total_loss])

  # Attach a scalar summary to all individual losses and the total loss; do the
  # same for the averaged version of the losses.
  for l in losses + [total_loss]:
    # Name each loss as '(raw)' and name the moving average version of the loss
    # as the original loss name.
    tf.summary.scalar(l.op.name + ' (raw)', l)
    tf.summary.scalar(l.op.name, loss_averages.average(l))

  return loss_averages_op


def train(total_loss, global_step):
  """Train CIFAR-10 model.
  Create an optimizer and apply to all trainable variables. Add moving
  average for all trainable variables.
  Args:
    total_loss: Total loss from loss().
    global_step: Integer Variable counting the number of training steps
      processed.
  Returns:
    train_op: op for training.
  """
  # Variables that affect learning rate.
  num_batches_per_epoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN / FLAGS.batch_size
  decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch * NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY)

  # Decay the learning rate exponentially based on the number of steps.
  lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE,
                                  global_step,
                                  decay_steps,
                                  LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR,
                                  staircase=True)
  tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', lr)

  # Generate moving averages of all losses and associated summaries.
  loss_averages_op = _add_loss_summaries(total_loss)

  # Compute gradients.
  with tf.control_dependencies([loss_averages_op]):
    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss)

  # Apply gradients.
  apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)

  # Add histograms for trainable variables.
  for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name, var)

  # Add histograms for gradients.
  for grad, var in grads:
    if grad is not None:
      tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name + '/gradients', grad)

  # Track the moving averages of all trainable variables.
  variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
      MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)
  variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())

  with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op]):
    train_op = tf.no_op(name='train')

  return train_op


def maybe_download_and_extract():
  """Download and extract the tarball from Alex's website."""
  dest_directory = FLAGS.data_dir
  if not os.path.exists(dest_directory):
    os.makedirs(dest_directory)
  filename = DATA_URL.split('/')[-1]
  filepath = os.path.join(dest_directory, filename)
  if not os.path.exists(filepath):
    def _progress(count, block_size, total_size):
      sys.stdout.write('\r>> Downloading %s %.1f%%' % (filename,
          float(count * block_size) / float(total_size) * 100.0))
      sys.stdout.flush()
    filepath, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(DATA_URL, filepath, _progress)
    print()
    statinfo = os.stat(filepath)
    print('Successfully downloaded', filename, statinfo.st_size, 'bytes.')
  extracted_dir_path = os.path.join(dest_directory, 'cifar-10-batches-bin')
  if not os.path.exists(extracted_dir_path):
    tarfile.open(filepath, 'r:gz').extractall(dest_directory)
```

file cifar10_input.py:

```
"""Routine for decoding the CIFAR-10 binary file format."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os

from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
import tensorflow as tf

# Process images of this size. Note that this differs from the original CIFAR
# image size of 32 x 32. If one alters this number, then the entire model
# architecture will change and any model would need to be retrained.
IMAGE_SIZE = 24

channel = 1

# Global constants describing the CIFAR-10 data set.
NUM_CLASSES = 2
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = 2310
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = 10000


def read_cifar10(filename_queue):
  class CIFAR10Record(object):
    pass
  result = CIFAR10Record()

  # Dimensions of the images in the CIFAR-10 dataset.
  # See http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html for a description of the
  # input format.
  label_bytes = 1  # 2 for CIFAR-100
  result.height = 24
  result.width = 24
  result.depth = channel
  image_bytes = result.height * result.width * result.depth
  # Every record consists of a label followed by the image, with a
  # fixed number of bytes for each.
  record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes

  # Read a record, getting filenames from the filename_queue.  No
  # header or footer in the CIFAR-10 format, so we leave header_bytes
  # and footer_bytes at their default of 0.
  reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
  result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

  # Convert from a string to a vector of uint8 that is record_bytes long.
  record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)

  # The first bytes represent the label, which we convert from uint8->int32.
  result.label = tf.cast(
      tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)

  # The remaining bytes after the label represent the image, which we reshape
  # from [depth * height * width] to [depth, height, width].
  depth_major = tf.reshape(
      tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [label_bytes],
                       [label_bytes + image_bytes]),
      [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
  # Convert from [depth, height, width] to [height, width, depth].
  result.uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])

  return result


def _generate_image_and_label_batch(image, label, min_queue_examples,
                                    batch_size, shuffle):
  # Create a queue that shuffles the examples, and then
  # read 'batch_size' images + labels from the example queue.
  num_preprocess_threads = 16
  if shuffle:
    images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
        capacity=min_queue_examples + channel * batch_size,
        min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
  else:
    images, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
        [image, label],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
        capacity=min_queue_examples + channel * batch_size)

  # Display the training images in the visualizer.
  tf.summary.image('images', images)

  return images, tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])


def distorted_inputs(data_dir, batch_size):
  filenames = ['captain_nn_train.bin']

  # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

  # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
  read_input = read_cifar10(filename_queue)
  reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)

  height = IMAGE_SIZE
  width = IMAGE_SIZE

  # Image processing for training the network. Note the many random
  # distortions applied to the image.

  # Randomly crop a [height, width] section of the image.
  distorted_image = tf.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width, channel])

  # Randomly flip the image horizontally.
  distorted_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(distorted_image)

  # Because these operations are not commutative, consider randomizing
  # the order their operation.
  # NOTE: since per_image_standardization zeros the mean and makes
  # the stddev unit, this likely has no effect see tensorflow#1458.
  distorted_image = tf.image.random_brightness(distorted_image,
                                               max_delta=63)
  distorted_image = tf.image.random_contrast(distorted_image,
                                             lower=0.2, upper=1.8)

  # Subtract off the mean and divide by the variance of the pixels.
  float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(distorted_image)

  # Set the shapes of tensors.
  float_image.set_shape([height, width, channel])
  read_input.label.set_shape([1])

  # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
  min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
  min_queue_examples = int(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN *
                           min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)
  print ('Filling queue with %d CIFAR images before starting to train. '
         'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)

  # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples.
  return _generate_image_and_label_batch(float_image, read_input.label,
                                         min_queue_examples, batch_size,
                                         shuffle=True)


def inputs(eval_data, data_dir, batch_size):
  if not eval_data:
    filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'data_batch_%d.bin' % i)
                 for i in xrange(1, 6)]
    num_examples_per_epoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN
  else:
    filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'test_batch.bin')]
    num_examples_per_epoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL

  for f in filenames:
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
      raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)

  # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

  # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
  read_input = read_cifar10(filename_queue)
  reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)

  height = IMAGE_SIZE
  width = IMAGE_SIZE

  # Image processing for evaluation.
  # Crop the central [height, width] of the image.
  resized_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(reshaped_image,
                                                         height, width)

  # Subtract off the mean and divide by the variance of the pixels.
  float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(resized_image)

  # Set the shapes of tensors.
  float_image.set_shape([height, width, 3])
  read_input.label.set_shape([1])

  # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
  min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
  min_queue_examples = int(num_examples_per_epoch *
                           min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)

  # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples.
  return _generate_image_and_label_batch(float_image, read_input.label,
                                         min_queue_examples, batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False)
```

Could someone plz tell me what's the problem and how to modify the code to solve it?

Comment: Anyone could solve this? If there's question about comprehension due to my bad english skill, please comment.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong because you're presenting a large set of code, but one debugging technique you can use to track down where NaNs are being introduced is the add_check_numerics call: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_check_numerics_ops

Comment: If the error remains, it means that the error is not related to that part maybe. You probably changed something else. You better look for the reason of the error. The error is Nan in summary histogram for: softmax_linear/biases/gradients. Some post suggest to reduce the learning rate. Check https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/304